# I need help to join 3 tables in Knex without merging the like columns

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

I am still really new to using knex and my project I'm working on is stumping me. So my current problem is that I need to merge 3 tables: *movies, reviews, and critics* and the result that I need to achieve requires "critic_id", "created_at", and "updated_at" to be listed multiple times in the json. [This is the ER diagram for the 3 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3horK.png)

The JavaScript that I have written is: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW0yO.png)
The result looks like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbXny.png)
The acceptable result needs to look like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJPQp.png)

I have gone over this so many times and cannot figure out how to keep the critic_id and timestamps separate even if the values are the same. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi Eric, Please help us by posting in your code nicely in your question. When we have all your code we should be able to help you. Welcome aboard